# What is the most semantically correct way to listen for a click event using jQuery

Tags: jquery, coding-style, click

Guys can you please give me some insight to the proper way to listen for a click event using jQuery and the pros and cons of each:

```
.click(function() { ... });
```

or

```
.on('click', function () { ... });
```

I want to make sure that i'm consistant in my code.

Comment: They're both identical in your example. I prefer .on simply because it gives me more options. If all you need is a simple click event handler, `.click` is fine, so is `.on('click'`

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: ^^ That is the most important piece of information related to your question.

Comment: Why does which version matter? If he has .on, you at least know it's 1.7+. Obviously if .on didn't exist in his version he wouldn't ask this?

Comment: Semantics is about self-describing structures, which has nothing to do with what you're asking. You're asking about CODING STYLE which is something completely different.

Comment: Nice assumption there @KevinB.  Thanks for the info :)

Comment: The coding style I prefer is `.on('click', ...)` because sometimes create my own which I can't call using `.something()` so using the same syntax for each possible option is good, and `.click()` just calls `on('click')` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the jQuery `click` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

> This method is a shortcut for `.on('click', handler)`

So there is basically no difference to using `.click` and `.on` in that simple form. Though, by using `on` you get additional options. For example, you can pass in additional parameters such as a `selector`, or `data`. Ex: `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )` By passing in a `selector` for example, you can create a delegated event so that even when new items are added to the DOM, the event will still be triggered. For that reason alone, I tend to almost always use `.on`. But again, using `.click(function() {` or `.on('click', function () {` is functional equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose one could argue that `.on('click')` is trivially "better", since it reads more like English than `.click()`, and it doesn't have the added (miniscule) overhead of another function call.

Answer (score 1):

All of the comments seem to exhaust the idea that both

```
.click(function() {
```

and

```
.on('click', function () {
```

are equivalent (see http://api.jquery.com/click/).

While coding style itself may be subjective, consistency may be a bit easier to address. Using the `.on('click', function() {` version has the opportunity to be more consistent because you can pass the `on()` method various events. The fact that it has more use cases increases its usability and potentially increases consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Using .click() on the element itself or .on('click') is exactly the same, just a short hand method.

If you are in need of one consistent way of binding click events then, I think you should mostly always use .on()..... as this can also be used to delegate events as well. This way you can use this .on() for all event listening and not have to switch between using .click(), .submit(), .delegate(), .live() etc.

Not only this but readability. .('on', 'click'.....is far more readable than the other delegation methods.